# Give an example of a $3$-dimensional subspace of $P_4$ which contains the polynomials...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Give an example of a $3$-dimensional subspace of $P_4$ which contains the polynomials $3$+$2t^2$, $t^4$, and $1+2t+3t^3$.

I have no idea how to even get started with this problem. Can I get some help? (Studying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the three polynomials $p_1(t)= 3+2 t^2$, $p_2(t) = t^4$ and $p_3(t) = 1 + 2t + 3 t^3$ are linearly independent, then the can be used as a basis to form a 3 dimensional subspace.

To show that they are linearly independent, I need to show that if $\sum_{k=1}^3 \alpha_k p_k = 0$, then the $\alpha_k = 0$. This gives $\sum_{k=1}^3 \alpha_k p_k(t) = (3 \alpha_1+\alpha_2)+2 \alpha_2 t + 2 \alpha_1 t^2+3 \alpha_2 t^3 + \alpha_3 t^4  = 0$. If  we differentiate 4 times, we get that $\alpha_3 = 0$. If  we differentiate 3 times and set $t=0$, we get that $\alpha_2 = 0$. Just setting $t=0$ gives $\alpha_1=0$, hence these three polynomials are linearly independent.

So, a three dimensional space that contains the given polynomials is given by $S = \text{sp} \{p_k\}_{k=1}^3 = \{ \sum_{k=1}^3 \alpha_k p_k \}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^3}$, where $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are given by above.

Comment: Just curious if I'm missing the obvious, but where does the + 4t^4 come from? Did you combine the first two polynomials?

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question, I thought there were two polynomials. I will fix the response.

Comment: OK, I fixed it, sorry about that!

Comment: No prob! Just making sure. I'm reading your solution now. Thank you so much for your insight.

Comment: This answer was fantastic, albeit a bit over my head. I believe this is an Einstein Summation? I'm assuming part of what it does can be labeled synonymous with the definition of linear independent if it = 0. I will study until I understand.

Comment: Well, no, the summation convention you refer to is just a convention to avoid a proliferation of $\sum$ symbols, but that is not an issue here. The dimension of a subspace is the maximum number of linearly independent vectors that you can find in that space. A set of vectors $v_k$  is linearly independent iff the only solution to $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k = 0$ is $\alpha_k = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps $\text{span}\{ 3+2t^2,t^4,1+2t+3t^3 \}$? I suppose you need to argue that the set in question is indeed linearly independent, but that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: What exactly is P_4?

Comment: I'd expect that someone asking a question here would *at least* understand the symbols he's using...anyway, $\,P_4\,$ *usually* denotes the set of all the polynomials of degree less than or equal $\,4\,$, over some fixed and given field (usually, the reals)

Comment: Ah, that's pretty straight forward. It was unclear to me. Is the fact that the subspace must be 3-dimensional significant to the answer, or would I just span the polynomials and/or prove that they are linearly (in)dependent?

Comment: @LearningPython The question is a bit strange. It seems too simple. Maybe you are supposed to see this as a subspace for some other reason? The kernel of some map, the image of another? Any span is a subspace so my answer is true, but maybe there is a more interesting one...